# mysql not unique auto increment, primary key two fields

Tags: mysql, primary-key, unique, auto-increment

I want to create a table structure like this in MySQL:

```
id  |  area    |  name 
----+----------+------------
1   |  name-1  |  test 
    |          |
1   |  name-1  | value2
    |          |
2   |  name-2  | test-value
    |          | 
3   |  name-3  | test
    |          |
3   |  name-3  | test
```

ie. the primary key will be: `primary_key( id, area )` and the id will be `auto_increment`, but i only want the id to increment for every new unique area

is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not possible. You want `id` and `area` to be the primary key but in your example they are not unique.

If you define a table key it must be unique and in your example that would mean you need to include `name` in your primary key. But why not make just `id` the primary key and auto-increment it? That is the common usage.

**EDIT :**

You could create an extra field called `area_id` for instance. You can add the auto-increment functionality to the field likE this:

```
CREATE  TABLE `areas` 
(
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `area_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `area` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
);
```

Comment: thanks, i'll just have to do that. was trying to think of another solution because each area must have its own id. guess i'll just have to add another column - area_id. would it be possible to auto_increment the new column area_id so that each area would have an id similar to the id field in the example above?

Comment: Yes that is possible. An auto-increment field does not have to be a primary key. Another possibility for you might be to store the area data in one table and create another table that references the area table to achive that every area in your first table has only one entry. And then your `id`field would be unique.

Comment: unfortunately the second option isn't possible for the system i'm designing as I don't know what data would be stored in the area table ( its a plugin architecture so that would be determined by the plugin itself ). So how could i get the auto increment to work as it does in the above example (ie tied to the area field) ?