# Pause or manipulate auto increment colum in table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a page where a coach would select a team. The selected players gets assigned to an array $player_names. My table, to which I will upload the values in the array, has 3 colums.
selection_id(auto, increment), Fixture_id, and player_names

Now what happens is I upload the player_names to the database but. For each player that gets uploaded the selection_id colums increments. This is wrong because I want all the selected players to hold the same selection_id.

Any advice on how to tackle this problem will be greatly appreciated.

**Practical example:**

[image]

**All** the players in the image above should have the same selection_id. **Only when** the next team is selected **for a different fixture** should it **increment by 1**

**Selection_id**
selection_id is based on the team that gets selected on a previous page. Lets say a coach picks his 5 players for a fixture. Now the 5 players gets uploaded to the db. In the team table the selection_id gets assigned to the 5 players selected. What I am trying to do is have the same selection id with each team (5 players) selected for a specific fixture

Comment: Have the seperate table for players and insert the selection_id with playername eg. `id | player_name | selection_id => 1 | tendai |117 , 2 | Adrian | 117`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you please clarify a bit more for me

Comment: "This is wrong because I want all the selected players to hold the same selection_id." -What does selected player means here .Is it based on some team or some other column in DB ?

Comment: selection_id is based on the team that gets selected on a previous page. Lets say a coach picks his 5 players for a fixture. Now the 5 players gets uploaded to the db. In the team table the selection_id gets assigned to the 5 players selected. What I am trying to do is have the same selection id with each team (5 players) selected for a specific fixture

Comment: Please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694064/mysql-not-unique-auto-increment-primary-key-two-fields?rq=1

Comment: Two separate tables is the obvious way to do this. Have one table that generates the `selection_id` and just holds the common information (in this case, it may just be `fixture_id`) and then a separate table that stores the information for individual players (and has a foreign key on `selection_id` back to the first table). The PK for the second table is either another autoincrement column that you don't care what values get assigned or it could be `selection_id, player_position`.

Comment: Also, you should insert not player names but their ids

Answer (score 0):

You have need two tables to manage same `selection_id` for selected players. `selection_id` should not auto incremented.

In first table `player_id` will be auto incremented.

```
+-------------+-------------+
|  player_id  | player_name |
+-------------+-------------+
|  1          | Tendai      |
|  2          | Andriaan    |
|  3          | Janus       |
|  4          | Eben        |
|  5          | Burger      |
+-------------+-------------+

+-------------+--------------+
|  player_id  | selection_id |
+-------------+--------------+
|  1          | 117          |
|  2          | 117          |
|  3          | 117          |
|  4          | 118          |
|  5          | 118          |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Using join query you can get selected player for same `selection_id`